# Build fails without errors

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, frameworks

I am using VS2013, and I am building against Framework 4.5.2.
I don't use any special or custom DLL / assembly references.

When I build my project, I don't get any errors, but the build fails.

I only get the warning

```
"Conflict between processor architecture of project "MSIL" which is being generated and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". (...)
```

When I build the project using Framework 4.5, it works flawlessly.

I am compiling for AnyCPU, and I am on a 64bit system.

Does anybody have any idea what might go wrong here?

Thank you!

ps: When I build using the developer cmd, I get the error

```
"Error BC30560: Extension attribute is not distinct in System.Runtime.CompilerServices
```

Comment: If you haven't already, try closing visual studio and re-opening. I've (and co-workers too) have seen lots of failed builds because it was storing some failure somewhere in memory. Even clean / rebuilds would continue to fail until we re-opened.

Comment: @John Unfortunately this did not help. I have tried the dev cmd and edited my posting with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the Framework 4.5.2 developer pack, and the error was gone immediately.
Not sure why I had to do that again, but it worked for me.